# Jquery datepicker keypress to trigger button

Tags: datepicker, keypress, blur

I have a datepicker that is bind to the textbox

```
MakeDateField: function () {
    $(this).not(".dispField").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: '-100:+20', onSelect: function () { $(this).blur(); } });
    $(this).blur(function () {
        $(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));
        if (datePickerBlurFix == 0) {
            datePickerBlurFix = 1;
            if (isValidDate($(this).val()) == false) {
                $(this).val(convertDate($(this).val()));
                if (dateRegEx.test($(this).val()) == false && $(this).val() != '') {
                    if ($(this).val() != "today" && $(this).val() != "**No Access**") {
                        $(this).val('');
                        msgBox({ Msg: msgDateCheck, Title: applicationName + ' - Error', Width: 300, Type: 'warning' }, function () {
                            $(this).focus();
                            datePickerBlurFix = 0;
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        datePickerBlurFix = 0;
    });
},
```

My problem is when I press enter, the datepicker will automatic select today date. But it doesn't go in to the following code

```
 $("#<%=txtDateSendFrom.ClientID %>").keypress(function (event) {
            if (event.which == 13) {
                $("#<%=btnFilter.ClientID %>").trigger("click");
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
```

No matter how hard I press "Enter". I think this is because it has lost focus, but if I add one $(this).focus() in to the datepicker. It also didn't work, plus the window of the datepicker will remain opened.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank You